# Getting entity property name by database column with doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm working on a import function that receives mapped data. The data is mapped by database column names for the target system. The application is symfony2 and uses doctrine to manage the database.

The problem is, most of the entity property names are different from the column names. I was wondering if there is a way to get the property by column name. Else i'll have to update the database without using the enities, or create another mapping.

Cheers,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

Go through this class,

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Mapping.ClassMetadataInfo.html

getFieldName() method, you can get field names.